# Read input from user while ignoring CTRL-C

Tags: go

I'd like to read user-input in go and ignore the user's attempts to kill my process by trapping `CTRL-C.` I spin a goroutine to trap `CTRL-C` and also write to a channel. At this stage, I expect control to return to `case <-intr` in the main goroutine, but that's not happening.

Here's output from a run:

```
$ go run read.go 
Enter text: hello
Entered:hello

$go run read.go 
Enter text: ^CGot signal interrupt
Exiting signal handler..

Invalid input2
Interrupted.. Continuing
Enter text: ^C
Invalid input2
Enter text: ^C
Invalid input2
Enter text: ^C^C^C^C
Invalid input2
Enter text: ^C
Invalid input2
Enter text: ^C
Invalid input2
Enter text:
```

The first CTRL-C is trapped alright and soon after it exits, it appears that the main goroutine is executing `r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`

When I hit CTRL-C as input later, it is simply treated as text and the signal handler isn't invoked.

My code is below (goplay link: http://play.golang.org/p/LiKZMYGr00)

```
package main

import ("fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    intr := make(chan bool)

    signal.Notify(c,  syscall.SIGINT)
    go func() {
        s := <-c
        fmt.Println("Got signal", s)
        fmt.Println("Exiting signal handler..")
        intr <- true
        return
    }()

breakOutOfHere:
    for {
        select {
        case <-intr:
            fmt.Println("Interrupted.. Continuing")
            continue
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Enter text: ")
            r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
            text, ret := r.ReadString('\n')
            if ret == io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("Invalid input1")
                continue
            } else if ret == nil {
                text = strings.TrimSpace(text)
                if text == "" {
                    fmt.Println("Invalid input2")
                    continue
                } else {
                    fmt.Printf("Entered:%s\n", text)
                    break breakOutOfHere
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`signal.Notify` sends signal information to the channel specified, every time process receives signal. But in your code go routine completes, after first signal. So, It is not able to trap the signal again.

One simple way to do this is, you need to have a infinite loop with select clause in the go routine.

```
go func(c chan os.Signal, quit chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
            fmt.Println("Got interrupt signal")
            fmt.Println("Exiting signal handler..")
            intr <- true
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }

}(c, quit)
```

Here, Channel `quit` is used, to request go-routine to exit cleanly.

Comment: Returning from the signal handler goroutine was a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. However, when the signal-handler goroutine services the signal, I still expect the block under `case <-intr:` to be executed. Why isn't that happening?

Comment: @linuxfan The reason is that, when you are pressing Ctrl+C, `bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)` is actually reading from standard input. So, the main go routine is actually blocked, and control cannot go back to `select` clause. The block under `case <-intr:` will be executed, when control is returned from the `bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`.